# Magento 2: Checkout button on product page

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, jquery

Is there a way to add a 'Add to Cart and Checkout' button to the product page, so that the product is added to the cart and then takes the user straight to the checkout?

Comment: You mean you want to redirect to Checkout page immediately after adding a product to cart successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Magento used Ajax in product page. When pressing the add to cart button, the data will be sent to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php`. I have two suggestions for you.

Navigate to `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`, we can see `ajaxSubmit` function which will handle the response data from the server. It will check the back Url that it will redirect to if this url exists.

```
    success: function(res) {
                    ......
             //Line 70 ~ 80       
             if (res.backUrl) {
                        window.location = res.backUrl;
                        return;
                    }
```

And then, go to the cart controller `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php`. In `execute()` method, if a product is added to cart successfully, Magento will call a `goBack` method to resolve the response data.

```
protected function goBack($backUrl = null, $product = null)
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            return parent::_goBack($backUrl);
        }

        $result = [];

        if ($backUrl || $backUrl = $this->getBackUrl()) {
            $result['backUrl'] = $backUrl;
        } else {
            if ($product && !$product->getIsSalable()) {
                $result['product'] = [
                    'statusText' => __('Out of stock')
                ];
            }
        }

        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
    }
```

As can we see, the back url will get the url value from `$backUrl` argument or `$this->getBackUrl()`. If we set one, Magento will redirect to it. So, basically, we have two ways to redirect to checkout page.

**1.** We may rewrite the `execute()` method and add a back url(this way not recommend). For example:

```
 #vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php

     if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = __(
                    'You added %1 to your shopping cart.',
                    $product->getName()
                );
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
            }
            //Back Url here
            $backUrl = 'checkout';
            //return $this->goBack(null, $product); => Old code
            return $this->goBack($backUrl, $product); // New code
        }
```

**2.** We add a return url in the product page template, should rewrite also (easier way). For example, add a return url inside the product view form.

```
#vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

<form ...>
   ...
   <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout');?>">
   ...
</form>
```

More advanced, Magento has a config **STORES** > **Configuration** > **SALES** > **Checkout** > **Shopping Cart** > **After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart**. We can follow the logic of this option to build our own redirect.

Answer (score 0):

that's an ajax call, triggered by

jQuery.mage.catalogAddToCart.ajaxSubmit

so you could extend the widget ( here how: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/ ) adding your own function ajaxSubmitAndGoToCheckout or overwriting the exisiting one if you want to leave the phtml untouched.

The idea is to make a js redirect to checkout on request success.

Obviously, with the second option, ALL the request would redirect to checkout.

Michele

Comment: looking at the response callback there's a
if (res.backUrl) {
                        window.location = res.backUrl;
                        return;
                    }

maybe you could add this response attribute to redirect to checkout