# Ajax add to cart button in product detail page magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento-community, magento-2.1

I have check online demo of Magento 2 
http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/fusion-backpack.html
when we click on add to cart it add product via AJAX but i have Set up demo on localhost it don't to add Product to cart via AJAX.

Can anyone tell where is settings to enable ajax on add to cart ?

Comment: have you seen any error in console?

Comment: It will redirect to shopping cart page or others?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: it don't redirect to cart page but refresh on same page

Comment: Maybe it's because you are with blank theme. Try to switch to Luma and you will get AJAX add to cart.

Comment: I am using Luma theme

Comment: You should read more how AddtoCart Ajax works: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112199/magento-2-checkout-button-on-product-page/112281#112281

Comment: based on your given link, its working fine with ajax add to cart, Have you still problem for that?

Comment: @Rakesh yes, I still not able to get ajax to work on product detailed page, although the ajax on category page is working now.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**You have to just override addtocart.phtml file**

```
app/design/frontend/Packagename/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

> Replace "bindSubmit": false to "bindSubmit": true

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Remove cache and check its in detail page.

Comment: That was quick and easy. One thing though I have Changed Button text From "Add to Cart" to "Add to Bag" But when it is added to cart the Text Revert Back to "Add to Cart" Where to change it.

Comment: you can try to change name of add to cart from here vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv with replace in second column add to cart to add to bag

Comment: How/ where do i override the file vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: in your app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/i18n folder

Comment: I have override and updated the File `app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Catalog\i18nen_US.csv ` and updated cell in colum 2 corrosponding to 'Add to Cart' to 'Add to Bag' and then reindexed and cleared cache but the button text is still 'Add to Cart'

Comment: you have to put csvfile inside app/design/frontend/Vendorname/themename/i18n not your Magento_Catalog folder

Comment: Hello @Rakesh, I have similar issue and got solution from your answer. But in case of Ver 2.1.2. after ajax add to cart page is getting refreshed. You have any solution to prevent the page loading in Magento 2.1.2 ?

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple. Why on earth do they not just have this tied to a configuration setting!?

Comment: This doesn't work in magento 2.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

> **Add method to your class**

```
public function __construct(
    ......................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
    ......................................................
) {
    ......................................................
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
    ......................................................
}

public function getProductData($id)
{
    $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);
    return $collection;
}

public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
```

> **Add into your phtml file**

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProductData(11);
?>
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo "uenc"; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
            class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form]": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why productFactory + load and not productRepository->getById()? Also in here `$collection = $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);` $id is undefined