# Ajax request on add to cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I am new to the Magento, so not sure how we can implement this 
I want to send ajax request on Add to cart button on product detail page where I have to send the request to get stock from third party API.

Comment: product detail page

Comment: @Daniel_12 check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125681/ajax-add-to-cart-button-in-product-detail-page-magento-2

Comment: magento version 2.2.0

Comment: I know its default but i need to check stock in my third party api

Comment: @SureshChikani sure :) I will be take care of this thing in future but as of now do you know how can I implement this

Comment: The first way you can do with creating a plugin and do with afterGetSectionData and second way you make a events.xml file in etc of your custom module and do with observer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override file:-

> app/design/frontend/[vendorname]/[themename]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Replace "**bindSubmit**": **false**  To  "**bindSubmit**": **true**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```